# How to smooth Venn diagram edges

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

I have a Venn diagram created in Python but I don't know how to smooth all (also the internal ones) the edges.

[image]

My code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn3
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from matplotlib.path import Path


set1 = {i for i in range(150)}
set2 = {i for i in range(150 - 75, 350 - 75)}
set3 = {i for i in range(150 - 75, 150 - 75 + 20)}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
venn = venn3([set1, set2, set3], set_labels=('', '', ''))

circle1 = venn.get_patch_by_id('100')
circle2 = venn.get_patch_by_id('010')
circle3 = venn.get_patch_by_id('110')
circle4 = venn.get_patch_by_id('111')

circle1.set_edgecolor('none')
circle2.set_edgecolor('none')
circle3.set_edgecolor('none')
circle4.set_edgecolor('none')

path_data1 = circle1.get_path().vertices.tolist()
patch1 = PathPatch(Path(path_data1), facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='#d6d3d6', hatch='/', lw=0)
ax.add_patch(patch1)

path_data2 = circle2.get_path().vertices.tolist()
patch2 = PathPatch(Path(path_data2), facecolor='purple', edgecolor='#d6d3d6', hatch='\\', lw=0)
ax.add_patch(patch2)

path_data3 = circle3.get_path().vertices.tolist()
patch3 = PathPatch(Path(path_data3), facecolor='pink', edgecolor='#d6d3d6', hatch="\/", lw=0)
ax.add_patch(patch3)


path_data4 = circle4.get_path().vertices.tolist()
patch4 = PathPatch(Path(path_data4), facecolor='orange', edgecolor='#d6d3d6', hatch=".", lw=0)
ax.add_patch(patch4)

venn.get_label_by_id('100').set_text('')
venn.get_label_by_id('010').set_text('')
venn.get_label_by_id('110').set_text('')
venn.get_label_by_id('111').set_text('')

# Show the plot
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

How to achieve that?
What's the cause of the angular edges here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the PathPatch objects using only the vertices of the "circles" returned by matplotlib-venn. Without explicit codes, PathPatch defaults to LINETO, i.e. drawing straight lines between vertices. You will want to use both, vertices and codes, to initialize your PathPatch instances.

```py
path_data1 = circle1.get_path()
patch1 = PathPatch(path_data1, facecolor='yellow', edgecolor='#d6d3d6', hatch='/', lw=0)
# etc
```

Comment: It works. Thank you!